# Code Igniter 2.0 session issue

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am having a session issue in codeigniter 2.0. The reason I think is it caching the page. Here is my problem.

I created a page and to access this page a user login is required. The login works fine. When I logout then I again redirected to login page and thats perfect. But if I click Back button of my browser then it again take me to that protected page. Technically this page is not accessible now because I have already logged out. If I put the link of that protected page in browser then it ask me to log in but after logout the browser back button is having the issue.
Can anyone please guide me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's normal browser caching behavior. One of the way to fix that is to make sure that wherever users go from the cached page, their session will be checked, and if they've logged out in the mean time, they'll be redirected to the login screen, so no harm can be possibly done.